# Renormalization confusion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I'm starting to read about renormalization in the case of scalar field theory. I have some confusions.

I will consider momentum renormalization.

First, consider a theory with a coupling constant $g$. For some calculation, the integral go to infinite, so we introduce a cutoff $\Gamma$. Then for a particular amplitude we can replace all $\int d^Dk$ by $\int^\Gamma d^Dk$. Then, by example, we calculate $n$ process and the results are:

$$A_i=f_i(g,\Gamma)$$

and the n functions $f_i$ are certainly all different.

As I understand, just by demanding that a specific amplitude $A_k$ remain unchanged we can derive the RGE by:

$$\frac{\partial A_k}{\partial\Gamma}=\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial\Gamma}+\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial\Gamma}=0$$

so that we can find the function $g=g(\Gamma)$

If QFT works, it must be true that we can find a RGE $g=g(\Gamma)$ such that all the $n$ amplitudes remain unchanged when we run the coupling. Is it the case? If it is, what is the special conditions required for all the functions $f_i$ for such existence of RGE?

If it is not true, please point out where I have misunderstood.

And also, what is the difference between energy scale and cutoff?